# Difference between os.system and webbrowser

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-webbrowser

Here are two ways to open a new url on browser using python.

First way is `webbrowser` module.

```
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Another way is `os.system(command)`.

```
command = "open -a Google\ Chrome url"
os.system(command)
```

So what's the difference between above ways? And which is faster?

**My pc os is macos**

Comment: Have you timed them to see which is faster?

Comment: `webbrowser` will be much more portable...

Comment: @Turn How to test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webbrowser.open()` is a convenient tool for the job, and self-explanatory in the code, so I would use it. It will try to do all the magic for you.
How fast does it need to be? Do you find yourself opening hundreds of urls at the same time?

`os.system()` is a "low-level" command and unless you need power beyond what `webbrowser` can do, it is easier to get wrong.
Unless the command forks/returns immediately (like most browsers will do), it will also wait and hang your script until the command terminates.

Also it will require the command (`open`) to be on your `PATH` (so prefer absolute paths, e.g. `/usr/bin/open`) and may not always be the one you want, depending on where the script is executed. For example `open` links to `openvt` for me, and so would not work for me. (I'd need `xdg-open`.)

So `webbrowser.open()` will be more portable.